# Carregar conteúdo especifico de uma div que esta em outro arquivo html com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, div

Salve lista!
preciso de uma ajuda aqui, tenho um arquivo ".html" onde monto uma lista que esta configurado assim:

```
<!-- ... -->
<header>
    function Open(id) {
        console.log(id);
        var x = $("#div"+id);
        $.get("descrs/greanerydescriptions_pt.html #div_"+id, function(data) {
             $("#content").append(data);
         });
         $("#headercontainer").hide();
        return false;
    }       
</header>

<body>
<div class="container content" id="content">
</div>
<div class="container headercontent" id="headercontainer">
    <div class="card cardheader" id="_000">
    <img class="card-img-top cardimgheader" src="images/abobora.jpg" alt="Abóbora" id="imgh_000">
    <header id="hdh_000"><h2 class="title">Abóbora</h2></header>
    <div class="card-body" id="div_abobora">
    <p>Nome Popular - Abóbora</p>
    <p>Nome Científico - Cucurbita moschata Duch.</p>
    <div class="form-group" align="right">
    <a href="descrs/greanerydescriptions_pt.html#div_000" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnh_000" onclick="Open('_000')" target="_parent">Descrição e Plantio</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="card cardheader" id="_001">
    <img class="card-img-top cardimgheader" src="images/abobrinha.jpg" alt="Abobrinha" id="imgh_001">
    <header id="hdh_001"><h2 class="title">Abobrinha</h2></header>
    <div class="card-body" id="div_abobrinha">
    <p>Nome Popular - Abobrinha italiana, abobrinha verde, abobrinha</p
    <p>Nome Científico - Cucurbita pepo L.</p>
    <div class="form-group" align="right">
    <a href="descrs/greanerydescriptions_pt.html#div_001" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnh_001" onclick="Open('_001')" target="_parent">Descrição e Plantio</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <br>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```

O arquivo "greanerydescriptions_pt.html" ta configurado assim:

```
<!-- ... -->
</header>
<body>
<div class="card cardcontainer" id="div_000">
<img class="card-img-top cardimgcontainer" src="../images/abobora.jpg" alt="Abóbora" id="imgc_000">
<header id="hdc_000"><h2 class="title">Abóbora</h2></header>
<div class="card-body" id="div_abobora">
<p>Nome Popular - Abóbora</p>
<p>Nome Científico - Cucurbita moschata Duch.</p>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="card cardcontainer" id="div_001">
<img class="card-img-top cardimgcontainer" src="../images/abobrinha.jpg" alt="Abobrinha" id="imgc_001">
<header id="hdc_001"><h2 class="title">Abobrinha</h2></header>
<div class="card-body" id="div_abobrinha">
<p>Nome Popular - Abobrinha italiana, abobrinha verde, abobrinha</p>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

O código da função `Open(id) {...}` ta funcionando, mas ele trás o arquivo inteiro, e eu preciso que ele traga somente a div especifica que esta instanciada no evento `onclik="Open('_xxx');".

Nao sei como resolver isso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Agradeço

Comment: já tentou usar **load** do jQuery?

Comment: pow, @LeAndrade, da no mesmo

Comment: Será que dá no mesmo??

Comment: ja testei aqui, no segundo arquivo, so tem as divs, como coloquei na pergunta, mas tanto com o **load** como com o **get** ta trazendo a pagina iteira com todas as divs.
vou mudar mais uma vez pra ver, jah te digo se confirmou

Comment: fiz assim ó: `$("#content").load("descrs/greanerydescriptions_pt.html #div_"+id);` traz todas as M*das das divs que tem no arquivo, carai, jah to ficando com os dedos roidos de testar essa droga

Comment: Mas vc sabe qual a div que é para trazer?

Comment: A função `load` irá carregar o documento, se o que quer é apenas a id especifica terá que fazer isso ao lado do servidor, visto que terá que trabalhar no arquivo para então recuperar somente o necessário.

Comment: Ele quer carregar uma div, no caso com o **load** do jQuery se fizer assim por exemplo **load("pagina.html #umaDiv")** só é carregado a div **umaDiv** e não o documento todo. Só não entendi o **#div +id** que ele quer passar na função load.

Comment: Ele quer recuperar somente `#div_"+id` que esta no documento a ser carregado. Até aonde eu sei isso não será possível sem tratar o conteúdo antes.

Comment: Eh isso mesmo @NoobSaibot, eh exatamente como esta escrito na chamada do evento, ou seja: em `onclick="Open('_000');"` eu chamo a function, dai, `...load("blábláblá.html #div_" + id)`, onde "id" eh o parametro passado na chamada. Voce poderia responder aqui mesmo como eu teria de tratar o "conteúdo antes"?

Comment: o **#div_" + id @LeAndrade, no caso, ficaria `...load("blablabla.html #div_000")...` quando eu clicar na tag <a> que chama o evento com `...('_000'), ou ficaria: `..load("....html #div_001")` quando eu clicar no <a> com `...('_001') e por ai vai

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer isso:

```
$("#content").append($("<div>" + data + "</div>").find("#div_"+id));
```

Comment: isso funcionaria mesmo sabendo que o elemento **div_xxx** esta em outro arquivo amigo @Bruno Trócolis?

Comment: Assim do jeito que tá agora, tá meio estranho, mas funciono.

Comment: Pow fera, nao deu certo naum amigo, mas acredito que tenha de fazer igual como o amigo @NoobSaibot, isto e, tratar o texto antes de setar o valor de "content"  com a div do resultado.
Mas note no comentario abaixo:

Comment: se eu removo as tags <html>,<header> e <body> e deixo so as 'dives' no arquivo ele funciona, mas isso porque eu setei manualmente a propriedade "display" dela para "block" e todas as outras para "none", mas dai sempre aparece a mesma div, rerere

Comment: acredito que o comentario do amigo @NoobSaibot esteja correto, ou seja, deixo todas com a propriedade "display" do CSS delas para "none" e depois que eu receber o bloco de código trazido pela function eu mudo a propr "display" para "block" antes de dar o append, talvez, mas eu nao faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso em jQuery, rererere

Comment: Fala amigo, eu não saquei muito bem oque você quer fazer, mas acho que é carregar a `<div>` escolida na mesma página e esconder o resto, pra funcionar eu também troquei a teg `<a>` por `<button>`, funciono aqui comigo. Pra simplificar você poderia criar _greanerydescriptions_pt.html_ só com as `div's` ou usar `JSON`. Espero ajudar.

Comment: opa @Bruno Trócolis, eh isso mesmo, mas o que acontece eh que essa titica carrega a pagina inteira, e se deixo o greanerydescription_pt.html soh com as divs, elas ficam sem a formatação da folha de estilos e sem encode de caracteres